# Docker build giving error: Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

Creating a web project using Visual Studio 2017 with Docker support (linux) I am not able to start the example MVC project created within Visual Studio. Just yesterday everything worked fine. I checked the firewall, reinstalled Docker many times. Any ideas?

Build command (generated by visual studio):

> docker build -f
>   "C:\Users\User\source\repos\testDocker2\testDocker2\Dockerfile" -t
>   testdocker2:dev --target base  --label
>   "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio"
>   "C:\Users\User\source\repos\testDocker2"

Error: `

> Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while
>   waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
>   headers)

See the image below:

[image]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error from the console.

After checking the "Network Connections" settings, I saw that IP was set statically, but DNS setting was empty.

So I set a DNS value also retry after that, and it worked.

> Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/:
>   net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
>   (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

[image: Network Connection DNS Settings]